# How to run SQL trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I am completely new to SQL Server 2008 and I wrote a trigger and would like to be executed only of `hassubproduct` and `spdisplaytype` columns are updated or inserted and if they have a value and are not empty.

Any help is appreciated.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[hassubproductcheck] 
ON [dbo].[products]
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE products 
    SET hassubproduct = LTRIM(RTRIM(hassubproduct))

    UPDATE products 
    SET spdisplaytype  = LTRIM(RTRIM(spdisplaytype))
END
GO
```

Comment: Your trigger is updating the entire table for every insert and update. You also are executing two update statements when 1 would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines is probably more like what you want.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[hassubproductcheck] ON [dbo].[products] 
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER FOR INSERT, UPDATE 
AS BEGIN 
    Update p 
        set hassubproduct = LTRIM(RTRIM(i.hassubproduct)) 
        , spdisplaytype = LTRIM(RTRIM(i.spdisplaytype)) 
    from Products p 
    join inserted i on i.PrimaryKey = p.PrimaryKey
    where i.hassubproduct > ''
        OR i.spdisplaytype > ''

END
```

Comment: Hi Sean, Thanks for the tip. I have tried but I am getting errors of:
Ambiguous column name 'hassubproduct'.
Ambiguous column name 'spdisplaytype'.

Comment: Ahh yes...couldn't test this of course. You just need to add the inserted alias in the the trim functions. I will update momentarily.

Comment: Just as a best practice, I would enclose that or statement in (). Then whenre someone later adds anotehr and clause to it, they won't get unexpected results due to order of operations.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the below code to define the trigger.  This will help for updated. The same way we need to create one for inserted as well.

```
   CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[hassubproductcheck] ON [dbo].products]             
     AFTER UPDATE 
        AS
        INSERT INTO DBO.SAMPLE_TRIGGER
        SELECT hassubproduct, 'UPDATE(PREVIOUS)' [TABLE-UPDATE] FROM DELETED
        GO

      CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[hassubproductcheck] ON [dbo].products]             
      AFTER UPDATE
       AS
      INSERT INTO DBO.SAMPLE_TRIGGER
        SELECT hassubproduct, 'UPDATE (LATEST)' [TABLE-UPDATE] FROM DELETED
       GO
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing here. You have two triggers with the same name and the select statements are the same thing except the string constant changed.